# Separate one year from a data value; taking care of leap years

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This should be pretty simple but I can't get the syntax correct. So, I have a parameter dictionary as below -

```
paramDict = {
StartPostingDateFilter": {
        "msgPrompt": "Start date",        
        "dataType": "datetime",
        "tableField": [{"table":"TableName",
                        "field":"ColumnName"}],
        "value": ["2006-01-01"]
                         } 
             }

StartPostingDateFilter = paramDict['StartPriorDateFilter']['value'][0]
```

Now, I want to subtract one year from the "StartPriorDateFilter" user provided date value. How do I take care of it if it's a leap year? I want to achieve the below -

```
If, StartPostingDateFilter = '2006-01-01'
Then create new variable, NewStartPostingDateFilter = '2005-01-01'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dateutil:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import  relativedelta
from dateutil import parser
d = parser.parse(StartPostingDateFilter)
print((d - relativedelta(years=1)).date())
2005-01-01
```

You could also use datetime and replace catching feb 29th returning the year - 1 and feb 28th if it was:

```
d = datetime.strptime(StartPostingDateFilter, "%Y-%m-%d")

sub = d.replace(year=d.year - 1) if (d.month != 2 and d.day) != 29 else datetime(d.year-1, 2, 28)
```